# Adding a DLL to the GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly, gac

I have a DLL that I need to add to the GAC.  I do not have access to the DLL project the only three files I have are a DLL, and XML and a CHM file.  This DLL does not have a public token key and therefore if I try to install it using gacutil an error saying that a strong name must be used is shown.  How I am going to add this DLL into the GAC so then I can make reference to it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need to install it in the GAC? You can make references to assemblies whether they reside in the GAC or not; just deploy them with your application.

Comment: Basically I have an SSIS package which need to alter. When I add local reference to the DLL (right click on 'Reference' > 'Add Reference') from the edit script tasks the package is throwing an expectation due to this reference.  Now since in the production server (where the SSIS package is running) this  DLL can be found in the GAC I am suspecting that I need to add the DLL in the GAC of my local computer and see what happens... and continue with the alterations needed.

Comment: Create a strong name using "sn.exe utility" and yolu shall be able to add the assembly to the GAC, and being a strongly named assembly it will always probe in the GAC on any system

Comment: I have generated a strong name using the sn.exe utility but I cannot find a proper example that works on how to proceed.

Comment: Pretty irresponsible, contact the owner of the DLL and ask for an update.  Also ask for a change to the way he sets the version number, he's using a bad practice that cannot ensure the DLL is unique.

Comment: If the DLL is in the GAC on the production server, it must have a strong name. Have you checked you have the same DLL as the server?